# Laravel eloquent vs query builder - best coding approach

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have read a lot of articles and posts on the subject and I am still not sure what is the best way forward.  I know that QB is faster and sometimes less explicite in the code.

However I found that the easier way to get related field in eloquent is more complicated than QB.  What do you recommend?

MODEL Post

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

CONTROLLER PostController

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
    ->get();    

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->article = $post->article()->pluck('title')[0];
    $post->user = $post->user()->pluck('name')[0];
}
```

OR

```
$users = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'articles.title', 'users.name')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

if your all relations are well defined in models than i will suggest you to go with eloquent. if you face any problem with eloquent than i will suggest you use query builder.

Eloquent is really flexible easy to manage than messy SQL. Here is one example of eloquent with relations

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
    ->with(['article', 'user'])
    ->get();
```

calling your relation with method will load your model relations with one query. it will execute separate query for each relation call.

You can use query also with your eloquent model. you can perform all sql operations with this.

```
$query = Post::query()->with(['article', 'user']);
$posts = $query->orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)->get();
```

Comment: In the "eloquent with", @umefarooq how do I retrieve the correct user name and article title in a loop?  If I use $post->user->pluck('name')[0] and $post->article->pluck('title')[0] the value does not correspond to the ones for the user_id and article_id.

Comment: i think you don't need to pluck you can get name of user related to post or article $pos->user->name it will give you related user name. with pluck you are converting collection object to an array so you have to user following code $post->user->pluck('name')[0]. it is giving you first element of array always.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an either/or thing because Eloquent extends the query builder, so all the same functionality is available. You can write that final query as something like this:

```
$users = Post::join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'articles.title', 'users.name')
    ->get();
```

Your first implementation is also suboptimal. Don't call relations as a method - that would return a query builder instance. Also, performing a query in a loop is a big no-no - that creates N+1 queries. Instead you can eager load the relation to improve response times and eliminate the N+1 query, as in this example:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
    ->with(['article', 'user'])
    ->get();
```

You can also constrain eager loads if you only need some related items or just a subset of the data. Using a join in many cases is still more performant than eager loading because it requires one query rather than several, but sometimes a join isn't practical and eager loading helps in that context.

The main advantage of an ORM over something lower level is abstraction. It provides a cleaner interface to the database. In addition, it's more type safe - if something else uses the responses then type hinting the model class gives you a better guarantee about the structure of the data it contains than type hinting an array, which could in theory contain anything. Tools like Psalm can specify a shape for the data, but they can't validate it at runtime the way language-level type hints can.

As a general rule of thumb I'd use Eloquent unless there's a good reason not to. There are some rare queries that are particularly difficult to express in an ORM (I've found that with the WITH RECURSIVE CTE for instance, it's very hard to do in any manner other than with a raw query), and sometimes for very large responses hydrating the models can itself become a bottleneck, but these are very much edge cases. By and large the advantages of a proper ORM in terms of reasoning about your code, ability to typehint responses, easy resolution of N+1 queries via eager loading and better handling of relations far outweigh any minor performance issues from hydrating the models vs returning an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use debug bar to see difference between db query or eloquent.

in big data you will find that db is more faster .

if you wan't eloquent more effect ,but ofcourse not be the same as db query

use that technique

```
$posts = Post::with(['artical','user'])->orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
    ->get(['id','name','user_id','artical_id');    
// only fields that will be used 
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // you have data already don't call the relation here to get data
    $post->article = $post->article->pluck('title')[0];
     
   //also here 
   $post->user = $post->user->pluck('name')[0];
    
}
```

or you can do this // i think it's more better

```
$posts = Post::with(['artical:id,title','user:id,name'])->orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
        ->get(['id','name','user_id','artical_id');   
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // you have data already don't call the relation here to get data
    $post->article = $post->article->pluck('title')[0];

   //also here 
   $post->user = $post->user->pluck('name')[0];

}
```

Comment: There is still an issue...  $post->user = $post->user->pluck('name')[0] always gives me the first element of the array with a key that has nothing to do with user_id

Comment: you can remove index [0]

like this 

$posts = Post::with(['artical:id,title','user:id,name'])->orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
        ->get(['id','name','user_id','artical_id');   
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // you have data already don't call the relation here to get data
    $post->article = $post->article->pluck('title');

   //also here 
   $post->user = $post->user->pluck('name');

}

if this is helpful don't forget to make best answer

Comment: off course it wont work because the relation itself is belongs to one user and one artical

Comment: I don't get it.  This is the most simple relation query and it seems so complicated with eloquent.  So what is the simplest solution?

Comment: your relations means that
give me the user that has this post
or give me the artical that popst belongs to

the user has many posts and the post belongs to one user
so when you trying to get user relation it will only give you that user that post belongs to

same for articals

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229390/discussion-between-paul-godard-and-amr-degheidy).

Answer (score -3):

As I know `Eloquent` is better than `Query Builder`, because `Eloquent` have many cool features:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($sortField, $sortOrder)->get();
return view('post', compact('posts'));
```

And call the related tables in view:

```
foreach($posts AS $post) {
    $article = $post->article;
    $user = $post->user;
}
```

You can call your `articles` related to your `posts` in your blade file, I think it is a better way.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Using a join won't slow the query down unless your database tables lack appropriate indexes. Calling those relations in a loop as in this example will create two N+1 queries, and they WILL slow your application down.

Comment: This is one of the worst answer/advices. For every post instance, this makes 2 more queries just to get relation table. Use joins if you use raw sql, and check your orm's documentation to avoid one of the most common beginner mistakes with querying data, the n+1 queries.