# Laravel eloquent "with" the easy way

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66436635/laravel-eloquent-vs-query-builder-best-coding-approach) a few hours ago but I can not understand why Laravel eloquent is so complicated... once again I read many posts on the subject and not one gave me the solution to a very simple request.

Here is the simple example where a post belongs to one article and one user only.  So the relations are defined as below in the Post model:

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

I am quite new to Laravel eloquent... so I simply want to display a list of all the posts with their id, comment and related user name and article title as per relation defined in the model above.  I believe that is quite simple and I just learned the "with" today.

So in the PostController, I have:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
    ->with(['article','user'])
    ->get();
```

This gives me a collection with all the posts.

First question, do I have to manipulate the 2 related fields in such a way that they become easily accessible in the list view below?  Or can I avoid this in controller in anyway by putting it in the query?

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $post->article = $post->article()->pluck('article');
    $post->user = $post->user()->pluck('name');
}
```

In the above, the field $post->article lists all the article titles in an array (article field).

If I add [0] at the end, I get the first element of the array.

If I use [post->article_id] I get the wrong related title.

So nothing works the way I want... why is it so complicated???

Ultimately, here is what I need to do in the list view.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <p>{{ $post->id }} : {{ $post->comment }} by {{ $post->name }} from article {{ $post->article }}</p>
@endforeach
```

By doing the query in query builder instead, I get what I want immediately... so how to do the same in eloquent?

```
$users = DB::table('posts')
    ->join('articles', 'articles.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'articles.article', 'users.name')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what is making you misunderstand it, so here is an explanation.

First of all, you have two `belongsTo` relations `user` & `article` in your post model.

When you run this

```
$posts = Post::orderBy($sortField,$sortOrder)
    ->with(['article','user'])
    ->get();
```

You get a collection of Posts and with the article and the user in the attributes `$post->article` & `$post->user` respectively. That queryBuild will launch 3 queries, one for the posts, one for the articles and one final for the users.

Now, in your blade, you want to access the attribute `article` in your Article model wich is inside the Post model so you do it like this:

```php
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    .... from article {{ $post->article->article }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Notes: When you call `$post->article()` you get a query builder, so you follow it with a

- `first()` => instance of a model / null
- `get()` => Collection of instance of a model or empty collection
- `pluck()` => array of the attribute plucked
- `value()` => the value of the first element as if you used pluck
- ... (there are other ways to get results)

When you call `$post->article` without parenthesis, it will run :

- `first()` if the relation is a belongsTo
- `get()` if the relation is belongsToMany or HasMany or....

OR

It will give you the attribute if already fetched (either a collection or a model instance).

So, since you used `with('article')` in the first query (already fetched), $post->article will return an instance of the model Article and no new query will be run.

Comment: This is extremely clear.  I really do not know how I could have miss that?  Thank you @N69S for taking the time to reply... I will frame it over my desk ;)